# Exception when opening or creating new project in Blend 4

Tags: expression-blend

Hi
When I open or create a new projects Expression Blend 4 (Premium) throws an exception and shuts down.
The log says:
System.BadImageFormatException: Index not found.
To me this sounds like a 32/64bit problem but I have no problem running Expression Blend 4 (Ultimate) on another computer.
Both computer run Windows 7 64 bit and has 6gb memory.
Any suggesions?
/Jimmy

Comment: Update: I have uninstalled Expression Studio and Visuak Studio 2010.
Reinstalled (no luck) uninstalled again. reinstalled Expression Studio Ultimate (since I have Msdn) but still no luck. Its just a crazy problem:S

Answer (score 1):

What is most likely happening is that during the construction of UI elements exception is thrown and Blend can't cope with it. So you will have to find what throws that exception. 
To do that you will need:

1. Open the same project in Visual Studio
2. Go to Debug -> Attach to process
3. Find in the list Expression Blend and attach to it
4. Put a brakepoint in VS somewhere in the beggining of your app
5. Run app from VS
6. When you hit the brakepoint step while don't hit the exception or just resume and see where the project fails.